# Creating model classes from yml or xml file in doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have created yml and xml file using ORM Designer for doctrine 2, but don't know how to create model classes from that.
In doctrine 1, I was using following command in php file to generate the same :

> Doctrine_Core::generateModelsFromYaml(realpath("../application/configs/schema.yml"),
>   realpath('../application/models'), array('generateTableClasses' =>
>   true));

I f anybody can put light on this, he/she will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find better and ideal tool for generating "Entity class model".
You do not need to create model classes with CLI.

Use following ORM designer for this :
Doctrine ORM Designer 2.1.9.69

It provides option to create PHP model classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CLI for this.

```
doctrine orm:generate-entities /path/to/entities
```

See the [manual](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/tools.html#entity-generation) for more information.

Comment: Seems your answer is helpful, but my command prompt says "Doctrine is not recognized command", Seems I need to add doctrine somewhere so that command prompt can read it. Any help?

Comment: No, I am doing it manually. Actually, I am following this link : http://thingswithpixels.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-doctrine-2-part-1

Comment: I have a bin directory in my doctrine distribution (I installed using composer). There are `doctrine`, `doctrine.bat` and `doctrine.php`. At the bottom of your referenced tutorial also is a paragraph about the Doctrine CLI.

Answer (score 0):

pls try 'php doctrine-cli.php orm:generate-entities models' to generate entity classes, 'php doctrine-cli.php orm:generate-proxies' to generate proxie classes, 'php doctrine-cli.php orm:generate-repositories models' to generate custom entityRepository classes. For this you must have your doctrine-cli.php at the root directory of your app.